# Transformar array e String

Tags: php, mysql, array

Como transformo uma array semelhante a esta e Strings para gravar cada linha no banco de dados Mysql.

Vou precisar apenas dos dados de cada array ( date, site e Status )

```
print_r($arrayOut);

Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [date] => 15/12/2016 17:11
            [site] => AC SAO MIGUEL DOS CAMPOS - Sao Miguel Dos Campos/AL
            [status] => Endereço insuficiente para entrega
            [isOrigin] => 1
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [date] => 15/12/2016 17:11
            [site] => Objeto em devolução ao remetente  
            [status] => Endereço insuficiente para entrega
            [isOrigin] => 
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [date] => 15/12/2016 09:53
            [site] => Sao Miguel Dos Campos/AL
            [status] => Saiu para entrega ao destinatário
            [isOrigin] => 1
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [date] => 09/12/2016 17:08
            [site] => AGF JARDIM MARILIA - Sao Paulo/SP
            [status] => Postado
            [isOrigin] => 1
        )

)
```

Comment: Não é mais fácil usar a chave? ex `$array[0]['date']` ou dentro de um foreach `$array['date']`

Comment: Estás a usar PDO, como te estás a conectar??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode usar o `json_encode` para transformar em string.

```
$dataString = json_encode($arrayOut);
```

Caso queira tirar alguns campos, antes de usar o `json_encode` faça uma loop e tire os campos que você não deseja:

```
foreach($arrayOut as $arr) {

    unset($arr['isOrigin']);

}
```

Caso queira salvar um de cada vez no banco de dados, basta aproveitar o `foreach`:

```
foreach($arrayOut as $arr) {

    unset($arr['isOrigin']);
    $dataString = json_encode($arr);
    // inserir $dataString na coluna correspondente.

}
```

[json_encode](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.json-encode.php)

Comment: {"1":{"date":"15\/12\/2016 17:11","site":"AC SAO MIGUEL DOS CAMPOS - Sao Miguel Dos Campos\/AL","status":"Endere\u00e7o insuficiente para entrega  |  ","isOrigin":true},"2":{"date":"15\/12\/2016 17:11","site":"Objeto em devolu\u00e7\u00e3o ao remetente  ","status":"Endere\u00e7o insuficiente para entrega  |  ","isOrigin":false},"3":{"date":"15\/12\/2016 09:53","site":"Sao Miguel Dos Campos\/AL","status":"Saiu para entrega ao destinat\u00e1rio  |  ","isOrigin":true},"4":{"date":"09\/12\/2016 17:08","site":"AGF JARDIM MARILIA - Sao Paulo\/SP","status":"Postado  |  ","isOrigin":true}}

Comment: Assim saiu com Json encode, como separo ?

Comment: sim, isso é uma string, se quiser pode dar uma olhada na documentação: http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.json-encode.php

Comment: Você pode salvar assim no banco, e depois para usar basta trazer esse valor e usar o `json_decode`, que isso será transformado em array novamente!

Comment: Entendi, estava querendo ja gravar de uma so vez direto em cada linha do banco, vou tentar trabalhar com explode e tentar separar, mais isso ja e de grande ajuda,

Comment: Eu editei a resposta @MarcosPaulo, ve se te ajuda!

Comment: Perfeito, agora e so trabalhar aqui, obrigado!!!

Comment: Só atenção que após salvar assim no banco você não vai conseguir filtrar por campo @MarcosPaulo

Comment: @bfavaretto - estou trabalhando com as strings antes de salvar, assim sera salvo somente o que eu preciso!

Comment: @MarcosPaulo o que ele tá dizendo é que você não conseguirá montar querys com base nesses dados, entendeu?

Comment: @JuniorNunes, entendi, da forma que vc deu a dica ai esta perfeito para mim, ja estou conseguindo filtrar e esta gravando no banco somente o que eu preciso!!

Comment: @JuniorNunes - uma duvida, sera que consigo pegar somente o ultimo status desta array?